# Nginx ingress configuration for Kubernetes cluster hosted on windows

Tags: windows, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, docker-desktop

I am running Kubernetes cluster on my windows PC via Docker desktop. I am trying to create a very basic pod with a simple ingress configuration, but it doesn't seem to work. I thought the backend pod + service + ingress is a very basic setup, however I don't find a lot of help online. Please advise what I am doing wrong here.

My `deployment.yaml` file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

`service.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-cluster-ip
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 1234
      targetPort: 80
```

`ingress.yaml`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          service:
            name: test-cluster-ip
            port:
              number: 1234
```

This is what I see when I access localhost from the browser

[image]

Also, I would like to ask if it is uncommon to run Kubernetes on windows even for testing (especially with ingress). I don't seem to find a lot of examples in the internet.

Comment: What happens if you go to `localhost/testpath`? The Ingress Controller will expose services under the paths you specified in the ingress definition (and will answer 404 to all other paths by default)

Answer (score 0):

> I thought the backend pod + service + ingress is a very basic setup, however I don't find a lot of help online. Please advise what I am doing wrong here.

It is indeed a very basic setup. And your k8s deployment/service/ingress yaml files are correct.

First, check if you installed [NGINX ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#quick-start). If not, run:

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.1.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

After that, you will be able to reach the k8s cluster using the following URL:

```
http://kubernetes.docker.internal/
```

**But deploying ingress like this**:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          service:
            name: test-cluster-ip
            port:
              number: 1234
```

you  are configuring the ingress to rewrite `/testpath` to the `/`. And requesting url without /testpath will return 404 status code.

See more `rewrite` examples [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/).

**So, if you use the following URL, you will get the Nginx webpage from k8s deployment.**

```
http://kubernetes.docker.internal/testpath
```

Comment: I did what you said but still after browsing I got 404 error. I am working on windows and docker desktop